# Is there a way to get all variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, variables

Is there a way I can find all the variables in Ruby that begin with a particular string?
For example, I have the following variables in my ruby program:

```
ret_d = 1
ret_d2 = 23
```

Is there a function that will return `["ret_d","ret_d2"]`? The problem is that I do not have the set of all variables.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Kernel#local_variables` should do the trick.

```
>> ret_d = 1
=> 1
>> ret_d2 = 23
=> 23
>> local_variables
=> ["_", "ret_d", "ret_d2"]
>> local_variables.select{|v|v=~/^ret_/}
=> ["ret_d", "ret_d2"]
```

Answer (score 6):

If they're local variables, you could use `local_variables`. However, this sounds like a poor man's array. You might consider using an actual Array.